# Как можно сделать безопасную авторизацию на php+mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Мне нужна помощь по созданию безопасной авторизации на все районы на php и mysql. Читал во многих форумах, как можно сделать безопасную авторизацию, но все это не подходит, так как там не написано подробно, что и как. Поэтому обращаюсь с вопросом в надежде, что кто-то напишет объяснение. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю, как сделать простую авторизацию вы знаете.
Уровни безопасности:

1. Включается защита от SQL-инъекций. Вы это, конечно, уже сделали.
2. Логин+пароль, причем пароль не менее 6 символов. 
   Пароль хешируется с солью не менее 10 раз.
3. Передача пароля осуществляется в зашифрованном виде. Для шифровки используйте симметричное шифрование, ключ к которому передайте по схеме [El-Gamal(Эль-Гамаля)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption)
4. Все поля формы имеют случайное имя, хранящееся в сесии и переназначающееся при перезагрузке страницы.
5. Поле логин/пароль созается при помощи js из двух произвольных текстовых полей(коих может быть до ста), остальные убираются, при помощи того же js. Из $_GET запроса выуживаются именно ЭТИ два поля(система знает какие она преобразовала), причем если заполнены лишние, выдается ошибка.
6. После второй ошибки вылетает сложная капча. Лучше не менее двух строк.
7. По всему JS, отвечающим за безопасность, проходитесь обфускатором.
8. Cooldown-time(время паузы между неудачными попытками) - не менее 10 секунд. В случае повторения ошибки более 10 раз можно заблокировать адрес на часик.
9. Параноидальный: время сессии в такой системе - 5 минут, во время некоторых особо важных действий просить сделать паузу в 30 секунд(максимальное время исполнения скрипта на большинстве хостингов).
10. Добыть сертификат https... :)

Comment: <small>ОМФГ <b>knes</b> а почему всего 10 раз? :D
Давай уже 1000 чтобы наверняка xD Вообще мне понравилось, улыбнуло... Это вообщем для тех кто реально помешан на этом - вперед товарищи :D</small>

Comment: Эт точно! <h3> ☺</h3>

Comment: Каждый сможет выбрать необходимый минимум. Чаще всего, ограничиваются пунктами 1+6.  
Что касается количества хэширований - десяти раз достаточно, в принципе. В линуксе 100 раз, но это с установкой на будущее, чтобы не пришлось переписывать.  
Уже после двух раз становится проблематично пользоваться радужными таблицами.

Comment: А если использовать HTTP-auth? ☺

Comment: Ну нафиг. Это диалоговое окно, оно меня бесит. Кроме того, там куча ограничений и низкая динамичность. XD

Comment: Вот мне интерестно, кому прийдет в голову на переборе паролей задвать десятикратное хеширование... Еще и с солью, добавить к этому каптчу и уже ИМХО с головой достаточно...

Comment: Пользователь не узнает, что там десятикратное хэширование. Это знает админ сайта. Кстати, против перебора этот метод слаб: он не для этого сделан. Сделан он исключительно для эмуляции обратных функций, например, для методов радужных таблиц.